# Properties to JSON

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a properties files which contain the following text

```
var propertiesString = `
alerts.attachment-preview-unavailable=Preview unavailable for this file.
alerts.operation-failed-unknown=Oops, operation failed for unknown reason.
comments.actions.approve.all.success=All comments in this discussion are approved.
comments.actions.approve.one.success=Comment approved.
comments.members.phrases.someone-plus-others={{someone}} + {{countOthers}} others
`;
```

Now I am trying to convert these properties to JSON object which is the following

```
{
  "alerts": {
    "attachment-preview-unavailable": "Preview unavailable for this file.",
    "operation-failed-unknown": "Oops, operation failed for unknown reason."
  },
  "comments": {
    "actions": {
      "approve": {
        "all": {
          "success": "All comments in this discussion are approved."
        },
        "one": {
          "success": "Comment approved."
        }
      }
    },
    "members": {
      "phrases": {
        "someone-plus-others": "{{someone}} + {{countOthers}} others"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
var propertiesString = `alerts.attachment-preview-unavailable=Preview unavailable for this file.
    alerts.operation-failed-unknown=Oops, operation failed for unknown reason.
    colors.green=Green
    colors.red=Red
    comments.actions.approve.all.success=All comments in this discussion are approved.
    comments.actions.approve.one.success=Comment approved.  
    comments.actions.unpin.success=Comment has been unpinned.
    comments.actions.unsee.success=You marked this comment as unseen.
    comments.form.at-mention-restriction-on-pending-ideas=You may only @mention other moderators and the idea submitter while the idea is in pending approval.
    comments.form.attachment.upload.error.unknown=Oops, unknown error happened when uploading the comment's attachment.    
    members.phrases.someone-plus-others={{someone}} + {{countOthers}} others   
    time-ago.on.day-month=on {{day}}{{ordinalSuffix}} {{month}}
    time-ago.on.day-month-year=on {{day}}{{ordinalSuffix}} {{month}} {{year}}
    time-ago.week.0=Sunday
    time-ago.week.1=Monday
    time-ago.week.2=Tuesday
    time-ago.week.3=Wednesday
    time-ago.week.4=Thursday
    time-ago.week.5=Friday
    time-ago.week.6=Saturday`;

function propertiesToJSON(str) {
 str
 // Concat lines that end with '\'.
  .replace(/\\\n/, "")
  // Split by line breaks.
  .split("\n")
  // Remove commented lines:
  .filter((line) => /(\#|\!)/.test(line.replace(/\s/g, "").slice(0, 1)) ? false : line)
  // Create the JSON:
  .reduce((obj, line) => {
   const colonifiedLine = line.replace(/(\=)/, ":");
   const key = colonifiedLine
    .substring(0, colonifiedLine.indexOf(":"))
    .trim();
   const value = colonifiedLine
    .substring(colonifiedLine.indexOf(":") + 1)
    .trim();
   obj[key] = value;
   return obj;
  }, {});
}

console.log(propertiesToJSON(propertiesString));
```

Comment: Please add the code here, not on an external site.

Comment: You never `return` anything from `propertiesToJSON`

Comment: What if you have a property like: `alerts=foo` and another property like `alerts.x=boo`?

Comment: Evey dot will be broken down. for alerts=foo, {"alerts":"foo"} and for alerts.x=boo, {"alerts":{"x":"boo"}}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lodash library has a function `set` you are looking for

```js
var propertiesString = `
alerts.attachment-preview-unavailable=Preview unavailable for this file.
alerts.operation-failed-unknown=Oops, operation failed for unknown reason.
comments.actions.approve.all.success=All comments in this discussion are approved.
comments.actions.approve.one.success=Comment approved.
comments.members.phrases.someone-plus-others={{someone}} + {{countOthers}} others
`;

var result = propertiesString
  .split("\n") //divides lines
  .filter(Boolean) //removes empty lines
  .reduce((acc, line) => {
    _.set(acc, ...line.split("="));
    return acc;
  }, {})
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

As requested here is code with implementation of lodash method `set` with pure javascript without any external libraries

```js
const set = (obj, path, value) => {
    if (Object(obj) !== obj) return obj; // When obj is not an object
    // If not yet an array, get the keys from the string-path
    if (!Array.isArray(path)) path = path.toString().match(/[^.[\]]+/g) || []; 
    path.slice(0,-1).reduce((a, c, i) => // Iterate all of them except the last one
         Object(a[c]) === a[c] // Does the key exist and is its value an object?
             // Yes: then follow that path
             ? a[c] 
             // No: create the key. Is the next key a potential array-index?
             : a[c] = Math.abs(path[i+1])>>0 === +path[i+1] 
                   ? [] // Yes: assign a new array object
                   : {}, // No: assign a new plain object
         obj)[path.pop()] = value; // Finally assign the value to the last key
    return obj; // Return the top-level object to allow chaining
};

var propertiesString = `
alerts.attachment-preview-unavailable=Preview unavailable for this file.
alerts.operation-failed-unknown=Oops, operation failed for unknown reason.
comments.actions.approve.all.success=All comments in this discussion are approved.
comments.actions.approve.one.success=Comment approved.
comments.members.phrases.someone-plus-others={{someone}} + {{countOthers}} others
`;

var result = propertiesString
  .split("\n") //divides lines
  .filter(Boolean) //removes empty lines
  .reduce((acc, line) => {
    set(acc, ...line.split("="));
    return acc;
  }, {})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I do not have any lodash plugin. Could you try without lodash?

Comment: edited my answer to include implementation of the set function

Comment: hide the log for the first one

Comment: which part of it did not work for you? it seems to work just fine for me, it matches the criteria you posted in your question as well

Comment: I do not know what the problem, I have applied to your code here ( https://codepen.io/mdshohelrana/pen/agpeBZ). Please see what I am wrong?

Comment: i run your snippet and result that came out of it is `{"alerts":{"attachment-preview-unavailable":"Preview unavailable for this file.","operation-failed-unknown":"Oops, operation failed for unknown reason."},"comments":{"actions":{"approve":{"all":{"success":"All comments in this discussion are approved."},"one":{"success":"Comment approved."}}},"members":{"phrases":{"someone-plus-others":"{{someone}} + {{countOthers}} others"}}}}` which is exactly what you asked for, is it not?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, now it is ok.